# extract 7z file using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, 7zip, lzma

I was trying to decompress a 7z file using python, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I figured I could use the lzma module in python 3, but I can't seem to figure it out:

I thought it would work like the zipfile package:

```
import lzma
with lzma.open('data.7z') as f:
    f.extractall(r"<output path>")
```

but after reading the documents, it doesn't seems to.  So here is my question: How can you extract a 7z file using the standard package?  I don't want to call subprocess to extract the files using 7-zip because I can't guarantee that users have this software installed.

I've searched the internets and stack oerflow and noticed all the answers almost go back to using subprocessing which I would like to avoid like the plague.

Though there are similar questions on stackoverflow, the answers all still depend on 7-zip or the 7zip SDK.  I do not want to use the 7-zip sdk/exe for extraction because that assumes the users have the software installed.

Here is the properties from the 7z file:

[image]

Comment: @Tezirg this is for python 2 not 3

Comment: executing the above code, what output do you get ? any exceptions ?

Comment: @NabeelAhmed builtins.AttributeError: 'LZMAFile' object has no attribute 'extractall'

Comment: I think that this might be a duplicate of: [Python3: lzma unpack .7z file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743127/python3-lzma-unpack-7z-file)

Answer (score 23):

What about trying this?:

```
from pyunpack import Archive
Archive('data.7z').extractall("<output path>")
```

Comment: Marvelous, after `pip install pyunpack` and `pip install patool` it worked excellent!