# 7z command in Python 3.6 subprocess.run() on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, 7zip

I have a python script that should run 7z.exe with the command: "x" and switch " -o" using subprocess.run(). The script is as follows:

```
import subprocess as sb


zipperpath = "C:\\Program Files\\7-zip\\7z.exe"
dirname ="C:\\Users\\ajain\\Desktop\\TempData"
archivename="UnprocessedData_v3.7z"
outputfilename="foo"

sb.run([zipperpath,"x",os.path.join(dirname,archivename)," -o",os.path.join(dirname,outputfilename)])
```

Output is:
[image]
Although the return code is 0, the zip never gets unzipped.

Comment: I see 2 potential issues. First, you are passing " -o" instead of "-o". The second is the docs indicate that the `-o` and the directory need to be combined into the same arg.

Comment: I would like to think there's a native python 7zip extractor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132184/extract-7z-file-using-python-3

Comment: Can you add how is your command like you put in your console..?....work directly?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar The comment by "jordanm" perfectly resolves the issue. The command whether executed directly on the console or the program was not working correctly because of the syntax issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this :

```
import subprocess

# variable cmd is is your command line , like you put in your console 
cmd='7z.exe x UnprocessedData_v3.7z'

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdin=None,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# The output from your shell command in an array
result=process.stdout.readlines()
if len(result) >= 1:
    for line in result:
        print(line)
```