# How to extract multiple 7z file using Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, extract, unzip, 7zip

I would like to extract multiple .7z files using Python.
I've tried this, but it only extracted one file. I already put in a loop.

Below is what I've tried.

```
import os.path
import glob
from pyunpack import Archive

os.chdir("E:/DATA/raw")
for file in glob.glob("*myfile.7z"):
    print(file)
    Archive(file).extractall("E:/DATA/output")
```

The names of the 7z files are:

```
AHFWHSH_1438923_myfile.7z
KFWFAUF_3257485_myfile.7z
GDSHUHG_8975498_myfile.7z
```

My expected output folders are:

```
output1
output2
output3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extract 7z file using python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132184/extract-7z-file-using-python-3)

Comment: Please add `print(glob.glob("*myfile.7z"))` immediately before `for` loop and write what output does it give

Comment: @SanjaySS nope, its not answer my question

Comment: @Daweo I added it

Comment: @Cheries are names of files inside your archives unique among them all? If not unpacking subsequent might simply overwrite already extracted files

Comment: @Daweo yes, all that file are unique, that's why I used that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your expected output is output1, output2, output3, then you should add the index to the output path. You should also create the directories before extracting the files, by using `os.mkdir()`:

```
import os
import glob
from pyunpack import Archive

for i, f in enumerate(glob.glob(os.path.join("E:/DATA/raw", "*myfile.7z"))):
    dir_path = "E:/DATA/output" + str(i+1)
    os.mkdir(dir_path)
    Archive(f).extractall(dir_path)
```

Comment: Hi @Vito, thank you for your answer.
But I got an error: `ValueError: directory does not exist:E:/DATA/output1`

Comment: I've updated the answer by adding the creation of the output directories, right before extracting the files

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, it works. But I found that one of the result in the output3 missing 1 folder after extracting.